# PHP force download of a .app file?

Tags: php

I am trying to force the download of a .app file..

Tried the following but its just giving me a empty .app file:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Application.app");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

?>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code ?

Comment: Did you output the data? You have a bunch of headers here but are not actually sending the file down to the browser. See [`readfile()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Is your file 0 bytes? You say none of these work. So either you are hiding something from us or `Application.app` is 0 bytes.

Comment: Application.app is a Mac OS application file (well directory i guess)

Comment: You can't force a download on directories only files.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
```

with

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
```

and then output your file with i.e. `readfile()`. And I'd also suggest to get rid of `?>` tag. So it should be:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Application.app");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile('Application.app');     // replace Application.app with right filename or full path to subject file
```

Comment: Actually, `.app` files are `.zip` files in some cases

Comment: So what. he wants to force download. Once you download the header no longer matters

Comment: Good point. I guess if the browser is dumb like IE, it will tell you its a zip and rename it `.zip`. -_-

Comment: Added both but its still 0 byte :/

Comment: @Alosyius make sure your file is not actually empty. and that you place the path of where it is on the readfile.

Comment: Added that but again still 0 byte

Comment: @Alosyius as Prix said - check your source file if you got access to it and if it is not 0 byte long

Comment: Source "file" is a Mac application which basically is a directory

Comment: AFAIR .app is NOT a directory. But if you want to send out directory then what you really expect? Directory is not an entity that can be send.

Comment: You can actually send the directory however it will be the directory alone which is why it is 0 bytes, perhaps you want to zip it before sending.

Comment: Directory cannot be sent. If you could, then it would not be 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end:

```
readfile('Application.app');
```

Because you are not outputting the file content.

Comment: Still same problem, file is 0 byte :/

Comment: If the file even called `Application.app`?

Comment: does that file contains any info?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = "http://example.com/application.app"; 

header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/zip");  // proper octet-stream
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\""); 

readfile ($file); 
?>
```

If the file is not opening with the browser..

```
<?php header("Location: http://example.com/application.app"); ?>
```